# Linux Kernel 3.13: How to list gendisk's?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm reading the [online book](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/drivers.html) about Linux Kernel drivers, which looks very obsolete to me. For example, the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) can't find a variable `gendisk_head` (in kernel 3.13), which is supposed to point to a list of `gendisk` structures, available **inside** the kernel.

How can I list all the currently allocated `gendisk` structures from inside the kernel 3.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

```
void __init printk_all_partitions(void)
{
        struct class_dev_iter iter;
        struct device *dev; 

        class_dev_iter_init(&iter, &block_class, NULL, &disk_type);
        while ((dev = class_dev_iter_next(&iter))) {
                struct gendisk *disk = dev_to_disk(dev);
```